# Enterprise Data

Tags: c#, t-sql, security, encryption

We are developing a huge financial, budget and expense management solution and one of the requirements is the user data and postings collected by our app stored in sql server MUST be encrypted by user supplied key.

*We are using SQL server 2012,EF 6 and .NET 4.5.*

**What we have tried:**
We created  class library with two functions in c# that does the encryption and decryption.The assemblies are complied to sql assembly and that works fine using a single encryption key.

**The challenge:**
The database contain data from different users who supply different key.the question is
How do we store user supplied keys such that it's secure...e.g If a user lost/forgot the key used to encrypt their data..the app can recover it.. while the DBA who supports this database should NOT have access to the keys..?

if we have 1M users..that means million keys..the tables have relational references so it become tricky to encrypt each row differently per user...What's the industry standard in this scenario..?

Comment: Store the keys on a server the DBA does not have authority to access.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would like to preface this answer by stating that I don't pretend to know the industry standard in this scenario -- I don't.  That being said, here's what I would do.

In cryptography, there's an algorithm known as [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).  In summary, it would let you split the key into multiple parts:

1. User chooses their private key, and splits it into 4 parts (n = 4), where any subset of 2 parts (k = 2) is sufficient to reconstruct their secret.  You can vary n and k to suit your needs, where n would be the number of recovery options provided and k is the number that must be correct.
2. User then encrypts each part of the private key with their recovery options and sends the encrypted parts to the server to store.
3. When user requests file, server sends encrypted file to client who can then decrypt it with their key.
4. In the event the user forgets their key, they can request their encrypted key parts from the server, provide recovery answers in an attempt to decrypt at least k of them, and (hopefully) get their data back.

Notes:

- Server doesn't store answers to the recovery options.  This means it won't be able to decrypt the files without the user's help (unless you were to send the raw splits to the server as well, but that's a potential security risk).  In essence, you could help the user get back to their key, but all bets are off if they can't remember any of their recovery options (e.g. amnesia, Alzheimer's, untimely death).
- If the user were to change their secret key, every file would need to be decrypted and re-encrypted using the new key.  This could be a potentially expensive task.
- The sum of recovery options needed to remake the key must not be easy for an attacker to guess.  For example, if I have 4 recovery options of which I must provide 2, and my choices are phone number, best friend's first name, and some others, then this would not be secure.  There aren't very many possible choices, which would make that example combination very easy to brute force.

Comment: Interesting but the down side is the answers are relatively short. If someone is going to go to the trouble to hack the database they would figure out how to hack the keys.  Still +1

Comment: @Fayth...good response..but I don't want to anticipate the complexity it will bring at app level,..so maybe it would help if I asked..how do enterprises protect user data stored in sql database in a way that DBA and developers can't view user live data once system is in production?

Comment: @user3240727 Developer and DBA is a different question.  The answer is still put the keys on a server they don't have physical nor network access to.